# XSI: namespaces removing

Tags: xml, xslt

As part of my requirement, I need to route a response coming from my `dp:url-open` in Datapower tool, serialize it and then send it to another link.

Issue is that response is holding so many namespaces in its every element. I know its the kind of format generated automatically, but i need to remove them completely.

I went through few posts in internet and used `exclude-result-prefixes` at start of my XSLT and i am able to get rid of most of namespaces like dp and dpconfig related to Datapower, but `xsi:` and `xmlns:` are still appearing in my string. How to get rid of that one also?

Please note that I cant use another XSLT as suggested in few posts. Is there any other way, please suggest.

Below are the namespaces from serialized.

```
xmlns:SOAP-ENV=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xsi:nil="false"
xmlns:xsi="http://w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Comment: maybe the namespaces are used and therefore cannot be removed? - the one bound to the `xsi` prefix is used for sure since you have the `xsi:nil="false"` attribute

Comment: Actually every element in my XML is getting this namespace declaration. and namespaces were not expected by my destination. @Pawel

Comment: You would need to post an example of your input XML and the XSLT you are using, otherwise all answers you can get will be vague guesses at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet will generate an XML document without any namespaces. All elements and attributes are created with **[xsl:element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl%3aelement)** and **[xsl:attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes)** using the `local-name()` of the matched item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You may need a couple of additional templates to target the `xsi` Schema Instance attributes if you do not want propagate them into the output.

For instance, when the following is in your source XML:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="false"
```

it would generate the following **nil** attribute:

```
nil="false"
```

You could prevent that by adding an empty template matching on that specific attribute, or any attribute the `xsi` namespace:

```
<xsl:template match="@xsi:*" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```